# Append 2 json objects per div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to append two different JSON items per div. I empty the div before looping through the json and then append the objects.

But I need to append two per div and each item has to be different. 
Eg. div1 has img1 & img2, div2 has img3 & img4 etc.

This is the result I am getting -

```
                <div class="gallery-sub-slider">

                <div>
                    <img class="img1">
                    <img class="img2">
                    <img class="img3">
                    <img class="img4">
                    <img class="img5">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <img class="img1">
                    <img class="img2">
                    <img class="img3">
                    <img class="img4">
                    <img class="img5">
                </div>

            </div>
```

But this is the result that I need -

```
<div class="gallery-sub-slider">

                <div>
                    <img class="img1">
                    <img class="img2">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <img class="img3">
                    <img class="img4">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <img class="img5">
                    <img class="img6">
                </div>

            </div>
```

```js
      $.each(data.carImages, function(i){
        counter++;
        imgLink = data.carImages[i].imgLink;
        console.log(counter);

        $('.gallery-slider').append('<div><img src="' + imgLink + '" class="gallery-img" data-tag="' + i + '"></div>');
        $('.gallery-sub-slider').append('<div class="sub-gallery-item" data-index="' + i + '"></div>');

        $('.gallery-sub-slider div').append('<img src="' + imgLink + '" class="sub-gallery-img" data-tag="1"><img src="' + imgLink + '" class="sub-gallery-img">');
        
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looping through each data.carImage, you can consider first calculating the number of divs you will require:

```
var divCount = Math.ceil(data.carImages.length / 2)
```

And loop through those:

```
for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i++) {
    var firstImgIndex = i*2;
    var secondImgIndex = firstImgIndex + 1;

    var firstImg = data.carImages[firstImgIndex];
    var secondImg = data.carImages[secondImgIndex];

    // create your div now, with your first and second img, but you might have to check that secondImg !== null or undefined
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much right! It just seems to continue appending the rest of the items. So it goes 
<div>
<img class="img1"><img class="img2"><img class="img3">
</div>

<div>
<img class="img2"><img class="img3"><img class="img4"><img class="img5"><img class="img4">
</div>